# How to optimize an Sqlite DB file size of INTEGERs?

Tags: sqlite

I want to build a **20,000,000** record table in **sqlite**, but the file size is  slightly **larger** than its TAB-separated plaintext representation.

What are the ways to optimize data size storage, specific to sqlite?

Details:

**Each record has**:

- 8 integers
- 3 enums (represented for now as 1 byte text),
- 7 text

I suspect that the numbers are not stored efficiently (value range 10,000,000 to 900,000,000)

According to the docs, I expect them to take 3-4 bytes, if stored as a number, and 8-9 bytes if stored as text (maybe additional termination byte or size indicator byte), meaning 1:2 ratio between storing as int : store as text).

But it doesn't appear so.

Comment: [Yes](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#record_format).

Answer (score 3):

Your integers should take at least 3-4 bytes (3 Bytes for up to 2^24 =~ 16,000,000). Additionally SQLite always stores at least one byte for every column as size information (also for your 1 byte texts --> 2bytes in sum for each).

Some questions:

- Do you use a compound primary key or a primary key other than a plain integer?
- Do you use other indexes?
- Did you try to vacuum the database? (command "vacuum") -- a SQLite database is not necessarily auto-vacuum't, so when data is deleted, the space stays reserved.

One further:

- Do you already have your 20,000,000 entries or less? For small databases the storage overhead can be much larger than the real content size.